# How can I get an item inside a flex item to stretch 100% of the parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a group of cards that are all in a flex container so that they stretch out the same height.
How can I make the card__content stretch the remaining height so that the date will be at the bottom of the card? 
I've tried adding
height: 100%; which isn't doing anything. Why's this? What am I not understanding?

Html and css below

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article class="card">
        <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
           <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
          <div class="card__content">
            <h2 class="h5">This is a news</h2>
            <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small> 
          </div>
        </a>
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
           <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
          <div class="card__content">
            <h2 class="h5">This is another news</h2>
            <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small> 
          </div>
        </a>
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
           <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
          <div class="card__content">
            <h2 class="h5">This is another news with a very long title</h2>
            <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small> 
          </div>
        </a>
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
            <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
            <div class="card__content">
                <h2 class="h5">This is a another news with a really long heading</h2>
                <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small> 
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 15px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.card-link {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.card__content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
}

.card__image {
    background: purple;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


.card__date {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

A link to a codepen here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjBGrd#anon-login

Comment: your date is already at the bottom of the card. where do you want to place it?

Comment: @Irin I want it to stick to the bottom of the card - if there is a longer title I want all the dates to be aligned to the bottom - all 50px from the bottom of the card

Comment: I have write a code for you please check it out. @Jessica

Comment: @Irin unfortunately this doesn't work for me - having the date positioned absolute means that the margin on top doesn't do anything :-/

Comment: Do you make your card class relative? And if you make your date absolute you doesn't need to have margin-top

Comment: @Irin yes, but the date needs to be about 50px from the bottom of the card. When putting bottom 50, it runs into the heading. Putting extra padding on the heading doesn't work as cards without dates have too much space - the same card is used on sections that use the date and sections that don't :-/

Comment: You must didn't add this position: relative line to your card. Pls add this line as I did to my code

Comment: @Irin I did ? If i didn't then the date would not be positioned relative to the card - the problem is that it is positioned absolute and so the card does not respect the space it takes up

Comment: Now I m confused Jessica sorry I couldn't help you the way I did this might not help you. Someone post another answer have a look pls. Sry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using flexbox on the wrapping items and extending their children as required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-link {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card__content {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.card__image {
  display: block;
  background: purple;
  height: 100px;
}

.card__date {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="card">
    <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
      <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="h5">This is a news</h2>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni at repellat fugit veniam! Optio maxime tempora quis inventore pariatur architecto provident, ex quam ullam repellendus.</p>
        <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
      <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="h5">This is another news</h2>
        <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
      <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="h5">This is a another news with a really long heading</h2>
        <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change the date position to absolute to put it always at the bottom of the card no matter what is the text size.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.card-link {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.card__content {
  padding: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
}

.card__image {
  display: inline-block;
  background: purple;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.card__date {
  margin-top: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="card">
    <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
      <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="h5">This is a news</h2>
        <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
      <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="h5">This is another news</h2>
        <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <a class="card-link" href="www.test.com">
      <img class="card__image" src="card-image.jpg" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="h5">This is a another news with a really long heading</h2>
        <small class="card__date">30 May 2019</small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Irin, also add in some details of what changes you made so that someone having the same question can understand the answer easily...